# Reference to object in parent scope in C# - is it possible?

Tags: c#, reference, scope

I have a class which creates a "data-holder" object, and then modify this object with some modifier classes, similar to this:

```
public class Process {
    public void Run() {
        var dataHolder = new DataHolder();

        var firstModification = new FirstModification(dataHolder);
        firstModification.Run();

        var secondModification = new SecondModification(dataHolder);
        secondModification.Run();

        //etc.
    }
}

public class FirstModification {

    DataHolder data_holder;

    public FirstModification (DataHolder dh) {
        data_holder = dh;
    }

    public void Run() {
        // do something with data_holder
    }
}

public class SecondModification {
    // etc.
}
```

In this code, each modification constructor must receive `dataHolder` as a parameter, with corresponding boilerplate, duplicated code in the modifier classes.

So I would like, if possible and/or recommended, that each modificator object would "already know" about the existence of the living `dataHolder` object inside `Process.Run()` method (its "parent scope", so to say), with no need to pass it as a parameter to the modifier constructors.

EDIT: I am trying to implement the Pipeline (aka Pipes and Filters) design-pattern, inspired in what is described [here](http://keyvan.io/pipes-and-filters-pattern-in-net) and [here](http://stevenatkinson.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/pipeline-design-pattern/).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if DataHolder is the only thing you keep in those xxModification classes you might as well have just one of them and make all RunXx methods static and pass DataHolder to them OR have one class with RunXx parameters if you run groups of them

Comment: I updated the question with two links to the Pipes and Filters (Pipeline) design pattern I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 3):

> So I would like, if possible and/or recommended, that each modificator object would "already know" about the existence of the living dataHolder object inside Process.Run() method (its "parent scope", so to say), with no need to pass it as a parameter to the modifier constructors.

Possible? Yes, via a thread-local variable to maintain "the current `DataHolder` for this thread" (or just a simple static variable, even).

Recommended? No, I wouldn't say so. I see nothing wrong with you've got at the moment - what advantage do you think you would gain from making everything implicit?

There's nothing which allows you to go back up the stack and find local variables in the calling method though...

Comment: The advantage in my particular case would be because the classes have tight cohesion (each modifier class can only work inside the `Process` context. So, parameter-passing sounds reduntant and/or unnecessary to my ears. Actually, each `Modifier.Run()` method could be a method of `Process`, implemented as `partial` (hmm...)

Comment: @heltonbiker: Should they only be *created* within `Process` too? If so, they could be nested classes. It still feels fine to have the parameter though - that's the shared state, effectively.

Comment: My main goal is to have each modificator modular and independent of each other (to be tested independently, also). Having them defined in different files also helps to track each one's version, IMO.

Comment: @heltonbiker It seems have a conflict of interest; trying to make a class independent of process but still tightly coupled doesn't sound like a good idea. Perhaps you should consider making partial classes if you want independent source control files? Then you simply make different methods you can invoke.

Comment: @Tejs partial class with methods spread across different files sound a good idea to me. Actually, I am trying to implement, "by the book", the Pipeline (Pipes and Filters) design pattern as described in the links I added to the question.

Comment: @heltonbiker: Partial methods spread across different files *doesn't* sound like a great idea to me. It sounds like something which would be hard for a newcomer to the team to understand, for example. Even if you'd only *use* the modifiers in the context of `Process` in production, to the operations themselves make sense independently?

Comment: @JonSkeet each operation is independent because its inputs and outputs have overall meaning, being "milestones" of each subtask. Besides, each subtask could be achieved using a variety of algorithms or protocols (or even libraries), so it is important to keep them independent of each other, although necessarily dependent on the overall process (specifically the objects stored by `dataHolder`)

Comment: @heltonbiker: In that case I'd probably stick with exactly what you've already got. Although if you're creating a pipeline, I can't help but feeling that you should really be attaching each stage to the other, rather than to one common object holding all the state.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll consider this. Authors are consistent on stating that each design-pattern can be implemented in many possible ways, and I think I'll end up figuring out the subtleties. But I am much more assured now that some high-rep folks told me that my suggested implementation is a non-nonsense one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to *somehow* associate the instances

```
var firstModification = new FirstModification()
```

etc. with the actual data.

The current approach is not a bad one.  If you want your modification instances to have access to "parent scope", then you would have to pass the parent object reference into them.  That actually provides them with more access to the parent object than they actually need, which I would discourage.

Comment: The Modification classes will always be called from inside a `Process.Run()` function with a "living" `dataHolder` object. In Python, if I'm not mistaken, this is enough to make parent scope available to a function or method. I was wondering if this would happen somehow in C#.

Comment: No, there is no concept of "parent scope" in C#.  To create an association, the child must hold a reference to the parent (or as in this case, to something contained by the parent).  Shared scope is possible (e.g. singleton, thread static, etc.) but is not appropriate for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ref` keyword for your parameter.

```
...
var firstModification = new FirstModification(ref dataHolder);
...
public FirstModification (ref dataHolder dh) {
    // Make changes to dh
}
...
```

This will pass a reference to the dataHolder object from the Process class to your FirstModification method.

Comment: And how is that different from what he has now? What value does the ref add?

Comment: This answer shows a misunderstanding of what `ref` means. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: The way I understand the OP is that they would like for the dataHolder passed into SecondModification to be the affected dataHolder from FirstModification.  No?

Comment: @Joe yes, a single `dataHolder` should be successively modified by each modificator, being available at the end of the series of modifications.

Answer (score 0):

How about superclassing the Modifier classes and making the DataHolder object available from the Process class as a static variable?

```
public class SuperModifierClass
{
    DataHolder dataHolder;

    public SuperModifierClass()
    {
        dataHolder = Process.DataHolder;
    }
}

public class FirstModifier
{
    public FirstModifier() : base() // Is base called implicitly by default? I forgot...
    {
    }
}
```

Another option would be to look at inversion of control through frameworks such as MEF and Unity (google those terms). What these allow you to do in essence is to register objects which can be automatically loaded when instantiating new classes that have them as a parameter. You're going to say "well, if someone ever needs a DataHolder object, use this one" When you instantiate the modification classes through such frameworks, the 'container' as it's called actually resolves the parameter by asking if it's been registered and taking the registered instance.